# How can I modify a pandas dataframe I'm iterating over?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, scipy

I know - this is verboten.
But when optimize.curve_fit hits a row of (maybe 5) identical values, it quits and returns a straight line.

I don't want to remove ALL duplicates, but I thought I might remove the middle member of any identical triplets, without doing too much damage to the fit.

So I wanted to use iterrows, and drop rows as I go, but I understand I may be working on  a copy, not the original.

Or, I could just do an old-fashioned loop with an index.

How can I do this safely, and in such a way that the end parameter of the loop is updated each time I do a deletion?

Here's an example:

```
i = 1
while i < len(oneDate.index)-1:
    print("triple=",oneDate.at[i-1,"Nprem"],oneDate.at[i,"Nprem"],oneDate.at[i+1,"Nprem"])
    if oneDate.at[i,"Nprem"]==oneDate.at[i-1,"Nprem"] and oneDate.at[i,"Nprem"]==oneDate.at[i+1,"Nprem"]:
        print("dropping i=",i,oneDate.at[i,"Nprem"])
        oneDate.drop([i])
        oneDate = oneDate.reset_index(drop=True)
        pause()
    else: i = i +1
```

I assumed that when I dropped and reset, the next item would move into the deleted slot, so I wouldn't have to increment the index. But it didn't, so I got an infinite loop.

Comment: Please post sample data, your desired output and the code you have so far.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the , inplace=True option and it now works fine.